# Console and canvas clear themselves

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, canvas

I've been trying to make my own version of Minesweeper but for some reason the console and canvas always clear themselves every 500ms or so. It may just be a problem with my computer but I've already tried restarting and switching browsers (Chrome, MS Edge).
Can anyone help me?

Code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var tileCount;
var mineCount;
var tileSize = canvas.width / tileCount;

var tiles = [];

function draw() {
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; j++) {
      if (tiles[i][j].mine == true) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillText("M", i * 400 / tileCount, j * 400 / tileCount, 20);
        //"M" is for "mine"
      }
    }
  }
}

function init(tilecount, minecount) {
  console.log(tilecount);
  tileCount = tilecount;
  mineCount = minecount;
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) {
    tiles[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; j++) {
      tiles[i][j] = {
        covered: true,
        flagged: false,
        numb: undefined,
        mine: false
      }
    }
  }

  var temp = mineCount,
    x, y;
  while (temp > 0) {
    x = Math.round(Math.random() * (tileCount - 1));
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * (tileCount - 1));
    if (tiles[x][y].mine == false) {
      tiles[x][y].mine = true;
      temp--;
    }
  }
  //delete temp, x, y;
  update();
}

function update() {
  draw();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

canvas {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-style: solid;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MINESWEEPER</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>MINESWEEPER</h1>
  <br>
  <form>
    Tiles:<input type="text" name="tc" value="10"> Mines:
    <input type="text" name="mc" value="40">
    <button onclick="init(this.form.tc.value, 
    this.form.mc.value)">submit</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Stackoverflow won't let me post this because it's "mostly code", I guess I'll have to find a way to bypass their rules ._.

Comment: If you're having trouble with posting the code try to condense down what you're doing. for instance instead of all the pieces like images and stuff just leave the tiles and a singular image. It' can be a bit of a pain, but it's worth it. Some of the time it'll even cause you to discover the reason for the issue you're having as well!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it's because the form keeps submitting when you click the button.

One way to solve this is to pass in the event to the function, then use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form from submitting:

HTML

```
<button onclick="init(event, this.form.tc.value, this.form.mc.value)">submit</button>
```

JS

```
function init(event, tilecount, minecount) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //
}
```

Alternatively, and in keeping with best-practice, remove the inline JS and add the listener to the button in the JS code instead:

HTML

submit

JS

```
// Cache the form and button elements, and
// add a click listener to the button
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', init, false);

function init(e) {

  // Still preventDefault...
  e.preventDefault();

  // ...but assign the values from the cached form instead
  var tilecount = form.tc.value;
  var minecount = form.mc.value;

  //
}
```